# Restarting an Android activity in c#

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, restart

I am trying to restart the current activity in c# after the user clicks on a clear button.

All of the examples I have found online are written in java. What would be the c# equivalent of the following

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(YourActivityYouWantToRestart));
Finish();
StartActivity(intent);
```

Or you could use:

```
this.Recreate ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had answered this question, but I guess not. The above example did the trick.